# UIImage issue on backing to the previous view controller

Tags: swift, uiimageview

I have 2 view controllers:

- First one has a button to open second view controller by `Show (e.g. Push)` segue way
- Second one has a `UIImage` that has 4 constraints:

  1. Top: Image to Safe Area
  2. Leading: Image to Safe Area
  3. Trailing: Image to Safe Area
  4. Equal Height: Image to SuperView by Multiplier: `0.5`

Image `contentMode` is `Aspect Fill`

**Question:**

When I want to back to the first view controller, why the image eject the `UIImageView`'s frame:

[image: eject image from it's frame]

Comment: Can you add the project on question?

Comment: @trungduc, I can't ask a question about unexpected `contentMode` of `UIImageView` and `AutoSize` class behavior?!

Comment: Of course you can. But the information you give in the question isn't enough to give an answer. As I see your project in the image is just a demo project. So I ask to take a look at it to give you a helpful answer.

Comment: It's not a project. I didn't write down a line of code! It's all made by Interface Builder. I noticed all information. what you want to know more?

Comment: push segue is deprecated. why not use show segue?

Comment: @Haitus, I fixed the question. It's `Show (e.g Push)` btw

Comment: the first vc is embed in nav controller right?

Comment: @Haitus, right. but I think It's `UIImageView` issue. not `UINavigationController`

Comment: Inside your Attributes Inspector on the right, just tick `Clips to Bounds` for your ImageView. https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-NkreEYnrURY/WEzBsMDUKUI/AAAAAAAAD4g/w2GaD6Zt9GQHXrmBOo1MQdSLqWhDG52jwCLcB/s1600/clip.png

Comment: ow, what the ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add clipToBounds is true for supperView (in your case in `self.view.clipToBounds = true` for SecondViewController).

Another issue may be happened that is UIImageView's frame

Comment: this should be the accepted answer since it came first?

Comment: So glad when this can help u :p

Answer (score 0):

Because you use  content mode contentMode is `Aspect Fill` you have to set `clipToBounds` to true  if you will use another contentMode it will be correct